# Why does the following code translate to a new + dup op instructions in java bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode

Let's say I have a `Fraction` class:

```
class Fraction {
    ...

    /** Invert current fraction */
    public Fraction inverse() {
        return new Fraction(den,num);
    }

    ...
}
```

And this is what the bytecode of the above method turns out to be:

```
 0 new #1 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction>
 3 dup
 4 aload_0
 5 getfield #16 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction.den>
 8 aload_0
 9 getfield #14 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction.num>
12 invokespecial #27 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction.<init>>
15 areturn
```

I'm trying to understand why instruction at position 3 was put there in the first place. I'd say we'd only need to do the following to make it work:

```
 new #1 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction>
 aload_0
 getfield #16 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction.den>
 aload_0
 getfield #14 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction.num>
 invokespecial #27 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction.<init>>
 areturn
```

Why is not so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the bytecode for the constructor starts, there is no Fraction object. The `new` instruction allocates a `Fraction` object (uninitialized) from the heap and leaves a reference to it on the stack. The `dup` instruction is so that one reference can be used to call `<init>` and the second used for the `areturn` at the end.

Comment: invokespecial won't put a reference to the Fraction on the stack, then?

Comment: @devoured elysium `<init>()V` returns `void` not `Fraction`.

Comment: The use of method `<init>` is specified in the Java Virtual Machine Specification (Sections [3.9](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#12174) and [7.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Compiling.doc.html#4089)). Oddly, the specification that it is of type void is squirreled away in [Section 4.4.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#29292): _"[an instance initialization method] must return no value."_

Answer (score 10):

Your bytecode is incorrect. Let's step through it:

```
new #1 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction>
```

**Stack**: `Fraction` instance (uninitialized, only a pointer to memory)

```
aload_0
```

**Stack**: `Fraction` (still uninitialized), `this`

```
getfield #16 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction.den>
```

**Stack**: `Fraction` (still uninitialized), `this.den`

```
aload_0
getfield #14 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction.num>
```

**Stack**: `Fraction` (still uninitialized), `this.den`, `this.num`

```
invokespecial #27 <xyzTestes/system/fraction/Fraction.<init>>
```

**Stack**:

This is crucial. All `invoke` methods require the stack to contain `this` + all arguments. Both `this` and arguments are taken from the stack. After the invocation only a return value (if any) is placed on the stack. `<init>` has a `void` return type.

This means you will call:

```
areturn
```

On an empty stack, blowing out the JVM.