# Java bytecode "excessive" number of dup considered "poor" code?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, bytecode

This is a two part question, but wouldn't make sense by the individual pieces.  Is a large number of `dup` instructions within the bytecode output an indicator of poorly written code?  Where large is defined by some percentage of all bytecode instructions.  Further how does one go about rewriting code that generates a `dup` instruction?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would provoke such a question?

Comment: I suppose you have checked the links on the right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594657/why-does-the-following-code-translate-to-a-new-dup-op-instructions-in-java-byt and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438567/java-bytecode-dup

Comment: @assylias yes of course.  However, they do not address my specific questions.

Comment: @delnan this question came about when I became curious about bytecode and how some legacy code was written.  As such there are a plethora of `dup` instructions in said bytecode output which screams to me that something is greatly amiss.  However, even after rewriting it in a less procedural way there are still many `dup` instructions.

Comment: `dup` just means a value is re-used, I don't see how that says anything about code-quality

Comment: @harold if that were the case why would my rewrite from very C style code into more OO code cause so many `dup` instructions to disappear?

Comment: @Woot4Moo, where did that code come from? Can you legally decompile it? Also, unusual patterns of instructions like that may indicate obfuscation. It could also mean it wasn't written in Java, but that's unlikely since it's legacy code.

Comment: @Antimony oh it is definitely Java.  Yes I can legally decompile it I am the one writing it.  Also I have the source available, which is why I know it looks like C instead of Java

Answer (score 8):

Are we talking about `javac` output you are analyzing or your own compiler/generator? If you are concerned about the quality of your Java code from the perspective of what `javac` produces - forget about it. First of all `javac` produces suboptimal bytecode and relies on JVM/JIT to do all the optimizations (very good choice). But still bytecode is probably much better than anything one can come up with quickly. It's similar to asking about the quality of assembly code generated by C compiler.

If you are generating bytecode yourself, excessive number of `dup` may look bad, but as well it might not have *any* impact on performance. Remember that bytecode is translated to assembly on target machine. JVM is stack machine but most architectures these days are register based. The fact that `dup` is used is only because some bytecode instructions are destructive (pop value from operand stack when reading). This doesn't happen with registers - you can read them as many times as you want. Take the following code as an example:

```
new java/lang/Object
dup
invokespecial java/lang/Object <init> ()V
```

`dup` must be used here because `invokespecial` pops top of the operand stack. Creating an object just to loose a reference to it after calling constructor sounds like a bad idea. But in assembly there is no `dup`, no data copying and duplication. You will just have a single CPU registry pointing to `java/lang/Object`.

In other words suboptimal bytecode is translated into "more optimal" assembly on the fly. Just... don't bother.

Comment: Hmm, do you have some resources that state why?  I have done my fair share of research and it seems that understanding the bytecode instruction set is critical for understanding what the program does at runtime.  If I can find the thesis that calls this out I will post it as a link.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: what kind of resources are you asking for? I agree that understanding bytecode is very important. I'm just saying that `dup` might not really trigger single CPU instruction. It's just an abstraction that will go away during JIT compilation.

Comment: That is the type of resource I am looking for.  Where it proves or at least alludes to in some cases that JIT tosses it away.  And i will accept a response of the big bytecode spec if that is indeed where it resides.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: it heavily depends on target platform. If you are familiar with low-level assembly, you can try enabling `-XX:+PrintOptoAssembly` while running your app with lots of `dup` and search for `dup`-like operations. I am pretty sure they will all be gone since reading CPU registry is not destructive.

Comment: So the second part of my question, how does one rewrite code to remove the `dup`?  Any insight on that?

Comment: @Woot4Moo: you mean: rewriting Java code to limit the number of `dup` instructions? It's like rewriting C++ to reduce the number of `mov` assembly instructions. However in C++ it might actually have some sense while, as I said, `dup` most likely disappears from assembly. Do you have any benchmark/evidence that `dup` is causing any noticeable performance drop?

Comment: The only benchmarks I have are the performance differences in the newly written code vice the old code.  The new code has 3 dup instructions the old, many many more.  The new code also has 1/3 the number of instructions as the old code.

Answer (score 2):

The `dup` instruction simply duplicates the top element of the operand stack. If the compiler knows that it's going to use a value multiple times within a relatively short span, it can choose to duplicate the value and hold it on the operand stack until needed.

One of the most common cases where you see `dup` is when you create an object and store it in a variable:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Running `javap -c`, you get the following bytecode:

```
0:  new #1; //class Foo
3:  dup
4:  invokespecial   #23; //Method "<init>":()V
7:  astore_1
```

In English: the `new` operation creates a new instance of the `Foo` object, and the `invokespecial` executes the `Foo` constructor. Since you need the reference on the stack to invoke the constructor and also to store in the variable, it makes a lot of sense to use `dup` (especially since the alternative, storing in the variable and then retrieving to run the ctor, could violate the Java memory model).

Here's a case where where the Oracle Java Compiler (1.6) *didn't* use `dup` when I would expect it to:

```
int x = 12;

public int bar(int z)
{
    int y = x + x * 3;
    return y + z;
}
```

I'd expect the compiler to `dup` the value of `x`, since it appears multiple times in the expression. Instead, itemitted code that repeatedly loaded the value from the object:

```
0:  aload_0
1:  getfield    #12; //Field x:I
4:  aload_0
5:  getfield    #12; //Field x:I
8:  iconst_3
9:  imul
10: iadd
```

I would have expected the `dup` because it's relatively expensive to retrieve a value from an object (even after Hotspot does its magic), whereas two stack cells are likely to be on the same cache line.

Comment: and the reasoning why it is cheaper?

Comment: "whereas two stack cells are likely to be on the same cache line"

Comment: Although, for all I know, Hotspot recognizes the duplicated `getfield` calls, recognizes that the object is not `volatile`, and caches the field value in a register.

Comment: Which just reinforces the dictum that micro-optimization is a bad idea. You'd be far better off posting old and new code and asking for comments. And better still by running a profiler.

Comment: Javac basically doesn't optimize. The bytecode is a near direct translation of what you write.

Comment: I agree on microoptimization, but  I dont think removing 2/3 of all instructions that get executed is a bad optimization.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - if you replace them with less efficient instructions it is. And even if you replace them with slightly more efficient instructions, but spend hours doing so, you're at a net negative.

Comment: irrespective, that is beyond the scope of my question.

Comment: @Woot4Moo It won't make a difference once the code is compiled at runtime. The only real difference is size of the classfile and minor differences in parsing and compilation time.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - That attitude is why there's so much lousy code in the world. But if you enjoy pointless work and your company is willing to pay you to do it, more power to you.

Comment: The attitude of fixing poorly written code is why there is so much lousy code?  Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean.  However, to say that my code is lousy after 1) I removed over 500 lines of Java code and 2) Removed over 3000 extra instructions from a loop .  I think you don't understand what an optimization is nor do you understand even the most fundamental pieces of computer architecture.

Comment: "The attitude of fixing poorly written code [...]  Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean". Yes, you're misunderstanding. I am referring to a mindless focus on reducing the recurrence of a single opcode. As for the ad hom attack that follows ... do you feel better now?

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about the impact of `dup` and its relations on performance, don't bother. The JVM does just in time compilation, so it shouldn't actually make any difference in performance.

As far as quality of code, there are two main things that will cause Javac to generate `dup` instructions. The first is object instantiation, where it is unavoidable. The second is certain uses of immediate values in expressions. If you see a lot of the later, it could be poor quality code, since you don't usually want complicated expressions like that in your source code (it's less readable).

The other versions of `dup` (`dup_x1`, `dup_x2`, `dup2`, `dup2_x1`, and `dup2_x2`) are especially problematic since object instantiation doesn't use those, so it almost certainly means the later. Of course even then it's not a huge problem. All it means is that the source code isn't as readable as it could be.

If the code isn't compiled from Java, all bets are off. The presence or absence of instructions doesn't really tell you much, especially in the languages whose compilers perform compile time optimization.

Comment: The legacy code is very very procedural in nature and unreusable ( > 500 line functions and such)